# What's the difference between kwargs and e.g. scatter_kws in seaborn?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

Since seaborn uses matplotlib for plotting, most (all?) of its functions have some way to pass arguments to the underling matplotlib function that draws the plot. This is a good design that allows flexibility without cluttering the high-level seaborn functions with too many arguments.

However, there seem to be two separate mechanisms for doing this. Some functions simply accept arbitrary keyword arguments, and any that aren't recognized by the high-level function are simply passed to the underlying matplotlib function. Others require you to put additional keyword arguments into a dict.

For example, `seaborn.scatterplot` and `seaborn.lmplot` both AFAIK use `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` as the underlying plotting function. If we want to pass the `s` argument to `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` in order to to control the size, in `seaborn.scatterplot` we can just add it to the function call:

```py
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='mpg',y='weight',s=10)
```

but in `seaborn.lmplot` we have to stuff it into a `scatter_kws` dict:

```py
sns.lmplot(data=df, x='mpg',y='weight', scatter_kws={'s' : 10})
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but I've not been able to figure out why these different mechanisms are used. Is it due to some thing internal to the way seaborn works that is not visible to the end user? Is one style legacy, and the code is moving to a different style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`seaborn.lmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) has both `scatter_kws` and `line_kws` parameters.
The `scatter_kws` keyword dict is passed to an underlying call to Matplotlib's `scatter` function, while `line_kws` is passed to an underlying call to Matplotlib's `plot` function.

Since the underlying Matplotlib `scatter` and `plot` calls share some keyword parameters (such as `color`) in common, using two dicts allows the user to control both individually. That is, the user could specify the scatter plot color to be, say, red while the line plot could be blue.

In contrast, [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) sends all its keyword arguments to an underlying Matplotlib `scatter` call. So no disambiguation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`lmplot` plots a `regplot` onto a `FacetGrid`. A `regplot` consists of a bunch of points, for which `scatter` is used, and a line, for which `plot` is used.

Imagine you pass the argument `s` to every underlying matplotlib function. It would be passed on to `scatter`, where it serves its purpose, but also to `plot`, which doesn't have any `s` argument. Boom. Error.

Additionally, there are arguments, which are valid for both, like `color`; but you may want to have the regplot line be in a different color than the points.

That's why those functions in seaborn that *combine* several plot types allow for those separate arguments.